# Cannot connect to ssas server

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I'm creating a new 'Analysis Services Tabular Project' in Visual Studio and the first thing VS asks is:

*Select an Analusis Services instance to use while authoring tabular model projects.*

I fill in the server and try Test Connecection, the error message I get is:

*Cannot connect to server '[server name here]'. Reason: An error occurred while connecting to the server.*

The problem is (I think) that the SSAS resides in another domain then my workstation. Is there a way to use other credentials when connecting to SSAS?

Or are there ways to analyse the 'error' in more detail?

Comment: I believe you are correct saying re: another domain.Try to connect to the server using another domain user & if it fails then it is the problem.

Comment: I've just tested this from MSSQL Management Studio, it fails.. I must move to another domain with the machine I'm working on. Shame

Comment: You could add your account to the Analysis Services administrators using the following notation for the account: `domain\username`.

Answer (score 1):

If disabling the Firewall or opening the 2382 or 2383 port is not making any sense to make connection to the SSAS server then, there could be below issue. Which I have discovered by spending lot of time research.

To connect to SSAS, SSAS server must have a domain(active directory) installed on it. 
The client machine from which you want to access the SSAS must have in the same domain of SSAS server.
If the SSAS server have a no domain, i.e. it is in the default domain (means in WORKGROUP) & the client machine is also in the "WORKGROUP". Then for making  connection to SSAS, you have to create same user(with same password) on both the machine (on client & SSAS server). After that you have to add that user in the SSAS-Property-Security access. After that you have to login with the newly created user on the client machine & try for making connection to SSAS.